# Сортировка С# (sharp) Не сортирует

Tags: c#, сортировка, методы

Делаю сортировку. Но почему-то не сортирует, задача сделать сортировку по алфавиту, а если буквы одинаковы то по весу. Прошу помощи, не могу понять почему не хочет сортировать. Вот код. Пишу в MVS.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    public class Detal : IComparable, IComparer
    {
        string name;
        double vaga;
        public Detal()
        {
            name = "NoName";
            vaga = 0;
        }
        public Detal(string namee, double v)
        {
            name = namee;
            vaga = v;
        }
        public void Output()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Name is {0} || vaga ={1}", name, vaga);
        }
        public int Compare(Object x0, Object y0)
        {
            Detal x = (Detal)x0;
            Detal y = (Detal)y0;
            if (String.Compare(x.name, y.name) < 0)
            {
                return -1;
            }
            else if (String.Compare(x.name, y.name) == 0)
            {
                if (x.vaga < y.vaga)
                { return 0; }
                else
                {
                    if (x.vaga == y.vaga)
                    { return 0; }
                    else
                    { return 1; }
                }
                }
            else
            {
                return 1;
            }
        }
        public int CompareTo(Object x)
        {
            return Compare(this, x);
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\nСписок деталей до сортування:");
            ArrayList x = new ArrayList
            {
                new Detal("Gaika", 0.5),
                new Detal("Rama", 400),
                new Detal("Korpus", 660),
                new Detal("Bumper", 15),
                new Detal("Molotok", 1.5),
                new Detal("Koleso", 1.1)
            };
            Detal st = new Detal();
            for (int i = 0; i < x.Count; i++)
            {
                st = (Detal)x[i];
                st.Output();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: а где сортировка-то?

Comment: в `public int Compare` @yolosora

Comment: не, это метод, объясняющий алгоритму сортировки как сравнивать экземпляры класса. А вот самой сортировки у вас в коде нету...

Comment: Просто вызовите `x.Sort()` и если ваш метод `Compare` реализован правильно - будет выполнена сортировка. PS: не по теме, но почему вы используете нетипизированную коллекцию? Учитесь по старым книгам/видеокурсам?

Comment: @АндрейNOP, да старые примеры в университете. А какие есть современные сорт?

Comment: @IlyaBurmaka да хоть банально `List<Detal>`

Comment: Современные не сорт, а современные коллекции, хотя бы тот же `List<Detal>`, хотя они появились еще в C# 2.0, т.е. в 2006 г.

Comment: @АндрейNOP Вот научите вы детей хорошему, а он лабу не сдаст. Хотя потом меньше боли на производстве будет...

Comment: @AK тру стори кстати, вел практику как-то и потом студент не сдал из-за того что я предложил код модифицировать, а препод не знал такого способа. Косых взглядов со всех сторон было много!

Comment: @AK, если нормально разберется и объяснит преподавателю преимущества дженериков, то сдаст, а может и плюсик получит еще

Comment: Предлагаю закрыть вопрос как невоспроизводящийся.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проблема в этом месте:

```
if (x.vaga < y.vaga)
{ return 0; }
```

Этот код делает вашу функцию сравнения неантисимметричной. Допустим, `x.name == y.name`, и `x.vaga > y.vaga`. Тогда если сравнивать `x` с `y`, получим, что они равны. А если сравнивать `y` с `x`, получим, что нет.

Comment: Если `x.vaga < y.vaga` то 0 и если `x.vaga == y.vaga` то тоже 0

Comment: @АртёмОконечников: Ага, а вот если `x.vaga > y.vaga`, то не 0. Это неправильно.

Answer (score 1):

Непосредственно за сортировку отвечает интерфейс IComparable. Т.е. чтобы компоратор ("сравниватель") знал, как объект нужно сравнивать с другими такими же нужно реализовать метод

```
public int CompareTo(object obj)
        {
            return ...
        }
```

[Документация по интерфейсу IComparable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.icomparable(v=vs.110).aspx)

В вашем примере, внутри класса я бы предложил следующую реализацию метода CompareTo(). А интерфейс *IComparer* и его метод *public int Compare(Object x0, Object y0)* вам тут не нужны:

```
public int CompareTo(object obj)
{
    Detal target = (Detal) obj;
    if (name != target.name)
    {
        return name.CompareTo(target.name);
    }
    else
    {
        return vaga.CompareTo(target.vaga);
    }
}
```

Стандартный CompareTo() у системных типов уже имеет свою реализацию, поэтому вам не обязательно делать собственные проверки, вы можете просто использовать его возможности.

Для того чтобы вызвать сортировку списка вам нужно сделать это явно, т.е вызвав у списка метод .Sort();

Так же, в своём классе вы реализовали интерфейс *ICompare* - это интерфейс компаратора("сравнивателя"). Т.е. вы можете сортировать свою коллекцию с помощью разных компараторов и тогда логика сравнения переносится наружу непосредственно в инструмент.

При вызове у массива/листа метода .Sort() вы можете передать в него экземпляр своего компаратора, если вы этого не сделаете - будет использоваться базовый, который пытается использовать логику интерфейса *IComparable* у сравниваемых экземпляров

[Документация по интерфейсу IComparer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.collections.icomparer.compare(v=vs.110).aspx)